# Vector iterator + offset out of range error thrown incorrectly

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I have written code for an evolving neural network and one of my classes has the following member function:

```
bool Brain::makeLayer(int pos)
{
    int preSize = layers.size();

    layers.insert(layers.begin() + pos, std::vector<Cell*>{});

    return layers.size() > preSize;
 }
```

where layers is defined as `std::vector<std::vector<Cell*>> layers`

I am getting an error `vector + offset out of range` on the line `layers.insert(layers.begin() + pos, std::vector<Cell*>{});`

Through some debugging, the size of layers is 1 and pos is also set as 1.

I have tried testing with different values of `pos`, and if called directly `makeLayer(1)` works as intended...

How it should work, `layers.begin() + pos` should be equal to `layers.end()` for a vector of size 1, and so when `insert` is called at that position, it should simply insert a `std::vector<Cell*>{}` at the end of layers, but it does not and throws the aforementioned error instead.

Edit: The containing class `Brain` guarantees that any call to `makeLayer()` will have a valid value `pos` such that `layers.begin() + pos` never exceeds `layers.end()`, the crux of my question is that `insert()` is throwing an error when that should not be possible. A `std::vector` of size 1 should never fail on `layers.insert(layers.begin() + 1, val)` unless the system runs out of memory and it my system is not running out of memory.

Comment: Have you tried to create a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: moreover, you should really assert() your functions preconditions to check them as early as possible; otherwise, *undefined behaviour* will propagate merciless into god knows where ...

Comment: @Jodocus I cannot, every test I have run with base data types alludes to me being able to do this, but it is not so...

Comment: No [mcve], only a part of the error message... First thing would be splitting your line into 2 lines: `auto it = layers.begin()+pos; layers.emplace(it);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you want to append a value to a `std::vector`, you should just use `std::vector::push_back`.</s>

You are over engineering, since there is already a function for that purpose.

EDIT: I think the problem you're getting at is that when you add `layers.begin() + pos`, pos is probably bigger than `layers.size()`, that's why you aren't even able to check if `layers.begin() + pos == layers.end()`, you're incrementing an iterator out of bounds.

Comment: I want to add a new element to the vector at a certain position, it just happened to be 1 in this instance

Comment: When you debugged did you check if the value of `layers.begin() + pos` is really `layers.end()`?

Comment: I couldn't get that far as it would throw the error every time I attempted to check if `layers.begin() + pos == layers.end()`

Comment: Thats probably because `pos` is bigger than your `layers` vector size. You are "overshooting" the iterator. Could you check that too?

Comment: @Stephen you can't, a vector is contiguous, you need to add all the intermediate ones as well.

Comment: @RichardCritten when you use `std::vector::insert` it automatically moves every intermediate ones as well.

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think is going on @Stephen

Comment: @RicardoAntunes Through debugging, the value of pos is 1, and the size of layers is also 1, so it should be possible...

Comment: @Stephen It can't hurt to add `assert(pos<=preSize);`, you could have gotten confused somehow while debugging.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I have added it, but even stranger, this error only occurs in the Debug build of my project, not the Release build...

Comment: @Stephen sometimes the Release build ignores memory errors

Comment: Well, of course, the error is from the debug mode checking iterators, release mode just proceeds to do random nonsense.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I created a workaround, see my solution, but if my workaround works, then so should `emplace()`

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix the issue, but creates higher overhead (for obvious reasons).

```
bool Brain::makeLayer(int pos)
{
    int preSize = layers.size();

    layers = insert(layers, pos, std::vector<Cell*>{});

    return layers.size() > preSize;
 }
```

where `insert()` is defined as:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> insert(std::vector<T>tgt,int pos, T item) {
    std::vector<T> temp(tgt.size()+1);
    int tgtIndex = 0;

    if (pos > temp.size()) {
//this function is for debugging, first param is file name, then error message, then is the error fatal
        errorOut("Lib", "Cannot add element to vector because pos is out of range", true);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        if (pos == i) {
            temp[i] = item;
        }
        else {
            temp[i] = tgt[tgtIndex];
            tgtIndex++;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't fix anything, you've probably just moved the problem somewhere else waiting to bite you again...